# Highcharts Beta 3: Best Practice loading JSON data

Tags: json, highcharts, beta

whats the best practice to load series data via JSON into a given chart with the new Highcharts Beta 3 and the data.src.js?

Was reading about the `complete` in the docs in data.src.js and was not sure if it fits the BP way now to load multiple series data using `$.getJSON` from jQuery.

Would be great if you can provide an example.

The standard example provided by HS (for e.g. CSV, google): http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AYYCv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.src.js is a script which parse data only from googlespreadsheet / CSV and HTML object, bt not from your custom JSON.

"Complete:" is only callback, which is run after i.e csv or spreadhseed data load.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So i missunderstud the description in the data.src.js.